# How can I connect to a remote ipv6 mysql server using connector/C++

Tags: mysql, ipv6, connector

I have an ipv6 mysql server.
I wanna develop a windows's client using connector/C++ which can connect to my
mysql server.
If mysql uses an ipv4 address, I can program like this:

```
mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;  
Connection *con;  
Statement *state;  
ResultSet *result;  
/* init driver */  
driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();  
/* try to connect */  
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "123");  
state = con->createStatement();  
state->execute("use test");  
/* query */   
result = state->executeQuery("select * from testuser where id < 1002");
```

How do I program if I want to use an ipv6 address for mysql?
Please, thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to place the IPv6 address in brackets, for instance:

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://[::1]:3306", "root", "123");
```

Be sure that your MySQL server is actually listening on IPv6. [MySQL versions before 5.5 did not support IPv6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-support.html).

Comment: Thanks very much.I'v fixed it up. Both MySQL client and server's version need to be 5.5 up.